# How to a read raw mouse data in the form of either Delta or Pixel movement?

Tags: c#, mouse

Ill get this out of the way at the beginning, I know how to read POINTER or CURSOR data, I can get the X,Y coords and through a interval of some sort calculate mouse Δ or movement, but this falls apart when he mouse reaches the edge of the screen as every known method I have seen relies on the concept of the derived cursor movement and not the mouse device itself.

I am also aware of the ability to "capture" the mouse (cursor) in a predefined space and or constantly reset the position to keep the mouse from ever actually reaching the edge of the screen, but this will not work for me as I would like the mouse to remain fully usable and not in a trapped state.

Every single result I have found in my searches for an answer have yielded code that only cares about the mouse cursor, so please don't carelessly mark this as **duplicate** of some other answer that is just doing one of the above.

I find it hard to believe that there isnt a low level function out there somewhere that gets me raw data.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish your task, use the WM_INPUT API (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee418864%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#WM_INPUT). WM_INPUT messages are read directly from the Human Interface Device (HID) stack and reflect high-definition results.

Comment: So that reports X,Y coords, how can a mouse device have any concept of X,Y screen coords if it hasnt already been intercepted and converted into such by Windows.